# Is condensing the number of columns in a database beneficial?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-optimization

Say you want to record three numbers for every Movie record...let's say, `:release_year`, `:box_office`, and `:budget`.

Conventionally, using Rails, you would just add those three attributes to the `Movie` model and just call `@movie.release_year`, `@movie.box_office`, and `@movie.budget`.

Would it save any database space or provide any other benefits to condense all three numbers into one umbrella column?

So when adding the three numbers, it would go something like:

```
def update
  ...
  @movie.umbrella = params[:movie_release_year] 
    + "," + params[:movie_box_office] + "," + params[:movie_budget]
end
```

So the final `@movie.umbrella` value would be along the lines of "2015,617293,748273".

And then in the controller, to access the three values, it would be something like

```
@umbrella_array = @movie.umbrella.strip.split(',').map(&:strip)
@release_year = @umbrella_array.first
@box_office = @umbrella_array.second
@budget = @umbrella_array.third
```

This way, it would be the same amount of data (actually a little more, with the extra commas) but stored only in one column. Would this be better in any way than three columns?

Comment: Please dont do that. The save on space in minimal, and the waste in resurces trying to split the data again is awfull. Also trying to join table will be a pain

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Is it possible to calculate how much space it does save?

Comment: @JeffCaros It's going to take more space as you're no longer storing 3 integers, but a string. Integers will take up less space.

Comment: The varlena header takes space too. And the delimiters. Really. *don't do this*.

Comment: @CraigRinger What is a varlena header?

Comment: @JeffCaros Variable length columns need extra space to store how long they are and some other info about compression, out-of-line TOAST storage etc. So storing 16 bytes of uuid as bytea will use more than 16 bytes due to headers and alignment. Storing as `uuid` will use exactly 16 bytes. Storing as `text` is worst as it has to escape the binary too so it will probably use more than 32 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no benefit in squeezing such attributes in a single column. In fact, following that path will increase the complexity of your code and will limit your capabilities.

Here's some of the possible issues you'll face:

1. You will not be able to add indexes to increase the performance of lookup of records with a specific attribute value or sort the filtering
2. You will not be able to query a specific attribute value
3. You will not be able to sort by a specific column value
4. The values will be stored and represented as Strings, rather than Integers

... and I can continue. There are no advantages, only disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with comments above, as an example try to use **[`pg_column_size()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html)** to compare results:

```
WITH test(data_txt,data_int,data_date) AS ( VALUES
  ('9999'::TEXT,9999::INTEGER,'2015-01-01'::DATE),
  ('99999999'::TEXT,99999999::INTEGER,'2015-02-02'::DATE),
  ('2015-02-02'::TEXT,99999999::INTEGER,'2015-02-02'::DATE)
) 
SELECT pg_column_size(data_txt) AS txt_size,
         pg_column_size(data_int) AS int_size,
         pg_column_size(data_date) AS date_size
FROM test;
```

Result is :

```
 txt_size | int_size | date_size 
----------+----------+-----------
        5 |        4 |         4
        9 |        4 |         4
       11 |        4 |         4
(3 rows)
```